# I would like to see if one string value fits in the range of another, in R

Tags: r, string

I have two columns of protein data, one that contains a modification of an amino acid and the location, and another with a range. If the modification number falls within this range, I would like to generate another column and copy that string there. If there are no matches I'd like it to remain blank and not delete any rows.

```
# Sample data

# String with the protein modifications and numbers

ProteinModificationMotifs <- c(
    "Glycosylation_49, Glycosylation_255, Glycosylation_399, Glycosylation_437, Glycosylation_455, Glycosylation_536",
    "Glycosylation_32, Glycosylation_101", "Glycosylation_555"
)

# String with the ranges
AA_Range <- c("400-637", "0-50", "0-444")

# Creating a dataframe
peptide_df <- data.frame(ProteinModificationMotifs = ProteinModificationMotifs, AA_Range = AA_Range)

# Displaying the dataframe
print(peptide_df)

#The output should be another column

print(peptide_df$PeptideModificationMotifs)

    [1]"Glycosylation_437, Glycosylation_455, Glycosylation_536",
    [2]"Glycosylation_32",
    [3]""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here The check_range function extracts the modification numbers from each protein string and compares them with the range specified in the AA_Range column of the same row. All proteins with modification numbers falling within the specified range are then included in the third column (PeptideModificationMotifs).

```
#data
    ProteinModificationMotifs <- c(
      "Glycosylation_49, Glycosylation_255, Glycosylation_399, Glycosylation_437, Glycosylation_455, Glycosylation_536",
      "Glycosylation_32, Glycosylation_101", "Glycosylation_555"
    )

AA_Range <- c("400-637", "0-50", "0-444")

# Creating a dataframe
peptide_df <- data.frame(ProteinModificationMotifs = ProteinModificationMotifs, AA_Range = AA_Range)

# Function to check if a modification number falls within the range
check_range <- function(modification, range) {
  mod_numbers <- as.numeric(gsub(".*_(\\d+)", "\\1", strsplit(modification, ", ")[[1]]))
  range_values <- as.numeric(strsplit(range, "-")[[1]])
  return(mod_numbers >= range_values[1] & mod_numbers <= range_values[2])
}

# Apply the function to create a new column
peptide_df$PeptideModificationMotifs <- sapply(1:nrow(peptide_df), function(i) {
  proteins <- unlist(strsplit(peptide_df$ProteinModificationMotifs[i], ", "))
  matching_proteins <- proteins[sapply(proteins, check_range, range = peptide_df$AA_Range[i])]
  return(paste(matching_proteins, collapse = ", "))
})

# Displaying the updated dataframe
print(peptide_df)
View(peptide_df)
1 Glycosylation_49, Glycosylation_255, Glycosylation_399, Glycosylation_437, Glycosylation_455, Glycosylation_536
2                                                                             Glycosylation_32, Glycosylation_101
3                                                                                               Glycosylation_555
  AA_Range                               PeptideModificationMotifs
1  400-637 Glycosylation_437, Glycosylation_455, Glycosylation_536
2     0-50                                        Glycosylation_32
3    0-444
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, if you're curious.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # separate, separate_longer_delim
peptide_df <- peptide_df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number())
peptide_df %>%
  separate(AA_Range, into = c("fm", "to"), sep = "-") %>%
  separate_longer_delim(ProteinModificationMotifs, delim = ",") %>%
  filter(between(as.integer(sub(".*_", "", ProteinModificationMotifs)), fm, to)) %>%
  summarize(Mod2 = toString(unique(ProteinModificationMotifs)), .by = rn) %>%
  full_join(peptide_df, by = "rn")
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#      rn Mod2                                                    ProteinModificationMotifs                                                                                       AA_Range
#   <int> <chr>                                                   <chr>                                                                                                           <chr>   
# 1     1 Glycosylation_437, Glycosylation_455, Glycosylation_536 Glycosylation_49, Glycosylation_255, Glycosylation_399, Glycosylation_437, Glycosylation_455, Glycosylation_536 400-637 
# 2     2 Glycosylation_32                                        Glycosylation_32, Glycosylation_101                                                                             0-50    
# 3     3 NA                                                      Glycosylation_555                                                                                               0-444
```

The `rn` column is added for easy grouping after range-determination; while we could work without it, it adds two things: it does not assume "perfect" comma-space-delimiters in the protein strings, and it unambiguously identifies rows where nothing is retained (by filling with `NA`). Feel free to remove it (`select(-rn)`).